# ASP.NET Gridview Sorting not functioning

Tags: asp.net, sorting, gridview

i m trying to implement a gridview on a web application, using asp.net. I m encountering a problem when it comes to sorting my datagrid, by a method - and i d like to ask for advice. This is my .aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridViewDemo1.Employee" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:GridView 
        ID="grvEmployee" 
        runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="true"
        BackColor="AliceBlue"
        ForeColor="Goldenrod" 
        BorderColor="YellowGreen"
        BorderStyle="Groove"
        Width="70%"
        CellPadding="3"
        CellSpacing="2" 
        AllowSorting="True"
        OnSorting="GridView1_Sorting" 
        AutoGenerateEditButton="true" 
        AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled">  


        <RowStyle 
            HorizontalAlign="Center">
        </RowStyle>

        <FooterStyle
            ForeColor="#8C4510"
            BackColor="#F7DFB5">
        </FooterStyle>

        <PagerStyle 
            ForeColor="#8C4510" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center">
        </PagerStyle>

        <HeaderStyle 
            ForeColor="White" 
            Font-Bold="True" 
            BackColor="#A55129">
        </HeaderStyle>

    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

and this is the .cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace GridViewDemo1
{
public partial class Employee : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        string selectSQL = "SELECT * from dbo.[User]";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds, "Employee");

        grvEmployee.DataSource = ds;
        grvEmployee.DataBind();

    }


    protected void GridView1_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //dataTable.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression;
        //grvEmployee.DataSource = dataTable;
        grvEmployee.DataBind();
    }


}
}
```

This is my web.config connectionstring:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxx;Initial Catalog=yyyyyyy;User ID=zzzzz;Password=xxxxxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The gridview gets populated properly, i used to get the "fired event Sorting which wasn't handled." but now i simply get no response from trying to sort a column. Does this even work with auto-generated columns? Where can i specify a sort expression? (Ascending/Descending etc)?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663532/How-to-Perform-Sorting-in-Gridview-in-ASP-NET or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23748174/gridview-sorting-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the initial DataBinding only if `!IsPostback` not on every consecutive postback:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    string selectSQL = "SELECT * from dbo.[User]";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSQL, con);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds, "Employee");

    grvEmployee.DataSource = ds;
    grvEmployee.DataBind();
}
```

In `GridView1_Sorting` you have to select the ordered data from the database and assign it to the grid's DataSource property, then call `grvEmployee.DataBind()`:

GridView Sorting Sample:https://stackoverflow.com/a/6602125/284240

Comment: So i would need to create a different sorting method for each column? Also, with this edit when i click on a column, the page simply goes entirely blank. Sorry for the trouble, really new at asp.net.

Comment: @onlyf: why one method for each column? You have already code in your method that uses `e.SortExpression`. However, there are plenty of quesuions on stackoverflow which show how to implement sorting with an ASP.NET GridView. I have also provided one some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6602125/284240